# Dump Just 1 table from SSH

Tags: mysql, dump, sql

With this command :

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname > 1.sql
```

You can dump dbname to 1.sql

I want a way to dump and restore just 1 table of dbname from ssh and command line

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a tablename to your command

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname tablename >1.sql
```

To recover

```
mysql -uuser -ppass -e "create database dbname;"

mysql -uuser -ppass dbname <1.sql
```

You may want to look at the [mysqldump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqldump) and [mysql](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql) man pages for further information.